# How to modify an angular components input value dynamically

Tags: angular

I am using an angular component within the component that I am creating. I cannot modify the component(DogstarComponent) that I am using.  It has an input value of "Alive" that I can set to true or false. However, I have multiple DogstarComponents in my html and only want to modify the "alive" input value of the one that I click. Whats the best way to do this? See example pseudocode below.

```
DogstarComponent.ts

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dogstar-selector',
    template: `
        <another-Component  class="test" [alive]="alive" header="{{title}}">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </another-Component>
    `
 })

export class DogstarComponent {

    //Title
    @Input() title: string;

    //alive
    @Input() alive: boolean = false;

}
```

dogstar-selector is used in a completely different components' (spaceships) HTML

spaceship.component.html

```
<dogstar-selector (click)="changeAliveValue();" [alive]="true" [title]="test"">

    <p> information </p>

</dogstar-selector>
```

spaceship.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'spaceship',
  templateUrl: './spaceship.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spaceship.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class SpaceshipComponent implements OnInit {

.......


changeAliveValue()
{

    //How do I change the input value of [alive]?


}
```

Comment: can you please provide your full thml markup for spaceship component , how you have multiple child component in it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Better ways are, use service for data sharing and use that service from those components. The following sample example that is not actually from your input

```
import {
 Injectable
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class StorageService {

 public entity: Array < any > | boolean = false;

 constructor() {}

 public getData(): Array < any > | boolean {
  return this.entity;
 }

 public setData(entity: any): void {
  this.entity = entity;
 }
}
```

Know more about this from the following link.
https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Answer (score 0):

if you have component under *ngFor you should do as below

spaceship.component.html

```
<dogstar-selector *ngFor="let index of list" (click)="changeAliveValue(index);" [alive]="selectedindex===index" [title]="test"">
</dogstar-selector>
```

spaceship.component.ts

```
selectedindex:number = -1;
changeAliveValue(index)
{
   this.selectedindex = index;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  this works however it also forces my other items in the ngFor list to turn false and I need them to stay true. I realize this should be a simple thing but I'm new to angular. Normally I would access the various vales in the dom using javascript, but I want to solve this in an angular fashion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the alive value of only one Dogstar component, just do it in that component.

```
dogstar.component.ts

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dogstar-selector',
    template: `
        <another-Component  class="test" [alive]="alive" header="{{title}}">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </another-Component>
    `
 })

export class DogstarComponent {

    //Title
    @Input() title: string;

    //alive
    @Input() alive: boolean = false;

    changeAliveValue()
    {
        this.alive = !this.alive
    }

}
```

Then in your `dogstar.component.html`

include: `(click)="changeAlivevalue()"` as an attribute on the HTML element that is being clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ViewChildren` to get a hold of the `alive` variable. How you display the components, with an ngFor (like Pranay shows) or just then individually insert the tags... here just inserting them individually:

```html
<dogstar-selector (click)="changeAliveValue(0);" [alive]="true"> ...
<dogstar-selector (click)="changeAliveValue(1);" [alive]="true"> ...
<dogstar-selector (click)="changeAliveValue(2);" [alive]="true"> ...
```

We pass the "index" to know which component variable to change.

In your parent component, import `ViewChildren` and `QueryList` and mark:

```ts
@ViewChildren(DogstarComponent) comps: QueryList<DogstarComponent>;

changeAliveValue(index) {
  // here we target the component chosen and toggle alive value
  this.comps.toArray()[index]['alive'] = false;
}
```

Here's a 
**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yefaqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**